# Cloze Passage - Grammar (Sequence of Tenses)

Tags: grammar, british-english, sequence-of-tenses

There is this sentence in my Grammar Cloze passage:

> Though I started off reasonably well, soon I felt my legs ___________(ache) badly.

Should I answer "ache" or "aching"? The correct answer is "aching".
I think "I felt my legs ache badly" is also correct. Can anyone explain to me why it should be "aching" instead of "ache"?

Thanks

Comment: This is one of many similar questions we are asked on ELU: "Why is answer **g** wrong here?" Here, none of the following three possible inserts gives an ungrammatical sentence, but I'll add suggested marks out of 5 for idiomaticity (how natural they sound to a mature Anglophone). (c) beginning to [5]. (a) aching [3]. (b) ache [1]. So the option I'd certainly use isn't even allowed. And while 'aching' works better than 'ache', I can't agree that it's 'correct' here ... just the best on offer. // 'Aching' is better than 'ache' as it refers to a continuous ...

Comment: state. But 'beginning to ache' manages to convey both the continuous state (contrast 'begin to ...') and the inchoativeness (the aching _starting_) that better matches 'soon'. We often end up criticising test questions (and answers) on ELU.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "Ache" on its own, would imply the infinitive wouldn't it? *I felt my legs (to) ache badly*. But I agree with you that it is less idiomatic than *aching*. Adding *beginning* changes the meaning slightly.

Comment: @WS2 'Soon' demands a change; 'Soon, it rained' sounds a lot less natural (though doubtless suitable padding can be found) than 'Soon, it began to rain'. To my ears. [And Google samplees.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Soon+it+began+to+rain%2Csoon+it+rained&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CSoon%20it%20began%20to%20rain%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csoon%20it%20rained%3B%2Cc0). As with 'Soon, it began to snow'. 'Thunder'.

Comment: The "correct" answer is still rather strange. Since *ache* already implies the connotation of *feel*, the phrase *Soon my legs were aching badly* is much more idiomatic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Seems that way with the weather, but *Soon my legs ached*, or *Soon I felt my legs ache* sound alright to me. I think the weather examples are perhaps unique. In reporting dialogue it "begins to rain", rather than merely "rains".

Comment: Because there's an onset implied.

Comment: Feel my leg aching is more correct.  Not sure, if OP is relating it to the usage of 'see'  where it can be used both ways like a)  He saw the car crash. b) She saw the car crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Aching** is preferable to “ache”, rather than ‘correct’.

**Aching** = in the process of aching. It implies that the feeling lasted for some time and had not finished at the time referred to, i.e. The ache is durative and in action at the time referred to.

**Ache** (v.) = to give one instance of an ache. The “ache” can thus be durative, or momentary, or part of a series of aches.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!